# Hide/show filters of ngtable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to add a toggle button for ngtable filters, but I can't figure out how I could achieve this properly. Of course I could just clear and hide the DOM elements, but thats just a horrible solution. I also tried just changing the attribute in DOM, but its never being evaluated again.

I am setting default value for the filters in the DOM:

```
<table id="my-table" ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
```

This will open the filters on default, but then I'd like to have a button that could be used to hide and show the filters again.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="toggleSearch()">Toggle search</button>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a variable that will help turn on and off the filter of ng-table. In the table tag:

```
<table id="my-table" ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="showFilter">
```

My button will set it appropriately:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showFilter = !showFilter">Toggle search</button>
```

In my controller .. I will set my `showFilter` variable to the default value ( true if I need to show the filters and false otherwise)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Also moved changing the showFilter value inside the toggleSearch() function so I can also clear the filters when hiding them.